# How to change NextPageText/NextPageUrl from "..." to "Next" in Gridview pager?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

The following is my markup for a GridView's pager

```
<PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="3" 
    FirstPageImageUrl="~/images/First.jpg" 
    LastPageImageUrl="~/images/Last.jpg" 
    NextPageImageUrl="~/images/Next.jpg" 
    PreviousPageImageUrl="~/images/Prev.jpg" />
```

However when I run it I get the default "..." as a link button to navigate to the next and previous pages. The first and last button navigation link buttons are shown as images properly.

Could someone tell me what's wrong?

**EDIT 1**

I get the same results with NextPageText as well

Comment: why dont you use [`NextPageText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.nextpagetext.aspx) ?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me; I forgot to mention that I tried that too but I get the same result.

Comment: Could it be possible that "..." is being set in your code? Which could cause the  `NextPageText="Next"` to be overwritten.

Comment: @nunespascal Nope. I just did a search and there were no results. I even checked in the Skin file but there was nothing for PagerSettings

Comment: I too have the same problem. This is frustrating.

Comment: After some research I found out that 'NextPageText' and 'PreviousPageText' does not work with  'NumericFirstLast' Mode. I cannot seem to override the pager either

Answer (score 3):

I also got the same problem and i solved with this code:

```
Protected Sub grdPatsCliente_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdPatsCliente.RowCreated
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Pager Then
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each ctl As Control In e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0).Controls(0).Controls
            i += 1
            If ctl.Controls(0).GetType.ToString = "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlPagerLinkButton" Then
                Dim lnk As LinkButton = CType(ctl.Controls(0), LinkButton)
                If lnk.Text = "..." Then
                    If i < 3 Then
                        lnk.Text = "Prev"
                    Else
                        lnk.Text = "Next"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            Dim x As String = ctl.ClientID
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The default Gridview Pager always render "..." on next and prev links. With this code i replace the "..." with my texts (also can use HTML like "<i class='fa fa-lg fa-angle-left'></li>" if you use [FontsAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/))

Code C#:

```
protected void grdPatsCliente_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager) {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Control ctl in e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0].Controls[0].Controls) {
            i++;
            if (ctl.Controls[0].GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlPagerLinkButton") {
                LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)ctl.Controls[0];
                if (lnk.Text == "...") {
                    if (i < 3) {
                        lnk.Text = "Prev";
                    } else {
                        lnk.Text = "Next";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this answer in VB.net? Can you post a c# solution please?

Comment: Thanks @TonioGago

Comment: Use grdPatsCliente.PagerSettings.PageButtonCount instead on "3" so there will be no depency.